Is web worker's stack on the SharedArrayBuffer?
Somebody told me that for a web worker everything is on SharedArrayBuffer except the js Object and .text segment (code segment). Is that TURE? I used to think that each web worker should had a private stack.
Additionally, is there any official reference or detailed explanation about the Web Worker memory model? Specifically, I’m curious about:

How stack and heap memory are managed in Web Workers.
How Web Workers differ from traditional OS threads or processes in terms of memory architecture.

Any insights or links to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated!

Uh… no, not even close to true. Nothing in a web worker is on a SharedArrayBuffer except for the SharedArrayBuffers you create. I wonder how whoever said that got that impression.

I see... thanks anyway
